# Win32 and AA modes in BluePrism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

What are the differences between win32 and AA spy modes in Blue prism. Please explain which spy modes to use in different scenarios

Answer (score 1):

Win32 and AA spy modes use different engines to find and match against a set of interface elements in the user environment. They use different attribute sets and matching methods to determine which elements to interact with.

Speaking from personal experience, the Win32 spy mode tends to be faster and more reliable, but Active Accessibility is compatible with more types of interface elements. When automating Windows-native applications, Active Accessibility should only be used when elements are not compatible or cannot be reliably targeted using the Win32 spy mode.

You can find more information about the attributes each spy mode returns to the Application Modeler by searching the following articles in the built-in Blue Prism help:

- Application Attributes - Win32 Mode
- Application Attributes - Active Accessibility Mode

You can also find more information as part of your Blue Prism Foundation Training guide in section **12.10. Active Accessibility**.